# Is it possible to update table cell borders in Google Slides using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm developing a script to programmatically change the color of a table in Google Slides but not seeing a method for updating the table border colors. I see a method for G-Sheets and G-Docs but not G-Slides.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does your research indicate?

Answer (score 1):

### It's possible with the [Advanced Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides)

- SlidesApp has a class [border](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/border#getDashStyle()), but it can only be used for [shapes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape), not tables
- However, the [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides) allows you to [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) a presentation with a [UpdateTableBorderPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetableborderpropertiesrequest)
- To use the Slides API within Apps Script, you need to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the Advanced Slides Service
- To fin the right syntax for your request, I recommend you to test it with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) before implementing in Apps Script.

**Sample for implementation in Apps Script:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var id = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId();
  var objectId = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getTables()[0].getObjectId();
  var resource = {
    "requests": [
      {
        "updateTableBorderProperties": {
          "objectId": objectId,
          "tableBorderProperties": {
            "tableBorderFill": {
              "solidFill": {
                "color": {
                  "rgbColor": {
                    "blue": 0.3,
                    "green": 0.7
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "fields": "tableBorderFill.solidFill.color"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, id);
}
```